# Log4j basic understanding

Tags: logging, log4j

I am starting to learn log4j.
Could someone explain what the following line does or means?

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE
```

Are there any recommendation on tutorials for log4j properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log4j.rootLogger` defines the level of the logger and where it outputs the logging requests to, that is it's appenders.

For further reading, refer [`PropertyConfigurator`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html#doConfigure%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerRepository%29) class of apache log4j api.

Answer (score 0):

**Configuring loggers**

The syntax for configuring the root logger is:

```
  log4j.rootLogger=[level], appenderName, appenderName, ...
```

More [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html#doConfigure%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerRepository%29).